# ERROR: syntax error at or near "settlement_date"

Tags: postgresql-9.1

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "settlement_date"
LINE 4:       if settlement_date > '2015-01-01'
                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "settlement_date"

SQL state: 42601

Character: 50

```
 update  "Recon".ship_error 
  set 
  if settlement_date > '2015-01-01'
              then
                        shipping_fee  = case

            when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                    when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -55

                when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <= 1  and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -55
        end
        end
        if settlement_date <= '2015-01-01'
          then
                            when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                    when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -43.4
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -24.3
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -43.4

                when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <= 1  and order_status !='return_completed' then -86.8
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -58.3
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -86.8
            end
      end 
     from "Recon".ship_error;
```

or i also tried this code

```
   update  "Recon".ship_error 
  set shipping_fee  = case

  when settlement_date > '2015-01-01'
              then
                        --shipping_fee  = case

            when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                    when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -55

                when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <= 1  and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -55
        end
        end
     when   settlement_date <= '2015-01-01'
          then
                            when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                    when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -43.4
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -24.3
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and order_status !='return_completed' then -43.4

                when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <= 1  and order_status !='return_completed' then -86.8
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -58.3
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 order_status !='return_completed' then -86.8
            end
      end 
   from  "Recon".ship_error;
```

Comment: Was there a question or are you just posting random error messages for our amusement?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support `if` clauses. You can use nested `CASE` clauses though.

Comment: i also tried nested case clauses  @SimoKivistö

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of errors in your query (a couple of times a missing `and` and extra `end` etc). Here is the query corrected:

```
UPDATE "Recon".ship_error
SET shipping_fee = CASE 
        WHEN settlement_date > '2015-01-01'
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NA'
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN 0
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL'
                        AND total_weight <= 0.5
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 55
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'LOCAL'
                        AND total_weight <= 0.5
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 29.4
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'ZONAL'
                        AND total_weight <= 0.5
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 55
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NA'
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN 0
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL'
                        AND total_weight >= 0.5
                        AND total_weight <= 1
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 55
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'LOCAL'
                        AND total_weight >= 0.5
                        AND total_weight <= 1
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 29.4
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'ZONAL'
                        AND total_weight >= 0.5
                        AND total_weight <= 1
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 55
                    END
        WHEN settlement_date <= '2015-01-01'
            THEN CASE 
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NA'
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN 0
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL'
                        AND total_weight <= 0.5
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 43.4
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'LOCAL'
                        AND total_weight <= 0.5
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 24.3
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'ZONAL'
                        AND total_weight <= 0.5
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 43.4
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NA'
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN 0
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL'
                        AND total_weight >= 0.5
                        AND total_weight <= 1
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 86.8
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'LOCAL'
                        AND total_weight >= 0.5
                        AND total_weight <= 1
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 58.3
                    WHEN shipping_zone = 'ZONAL'
                        AND total_weight >= 0.5
                        AND total_weight <= 1
                        AND order_status != 'return_completed'
                        THEN - 86.8
                    END
        END;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update  "Recon".ship_error 
  set shipping_fee  = case



                        --shipping_fee  = case

            when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                    when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and settlement_date > '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and settlement_date > '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and settlement_date > '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -55

                when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <= 1  and settlement_date > '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 and settlement_date > '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 and settlement_date > '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -55
                    when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                    when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and settlement_date <= '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -43.4
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and settlement_date <= '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -29.4
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight <= 0.5 and settlement_date <= '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -43.4

                when shipping_zone = 'NA' and  order_status !='return_completed' then 0
                when shipping_zone = 'NATIONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <= 1  and settlement_date <= '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -86.8
                when shipping_zone = 'LOCAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 and settlement_date <= '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -58.8
                when shipping_zone = 'ZONAL' and total_weight >= 0.5 and total_weight <=1 and settlement_date <= '2015-01-01' and order_status !='return_completed' then -86.8
            end ;
```